# Width of orbit slider

Tags: jquery, css, slider, width, orbit

I can't seem to adjust the width of the orbit slider

http://ashwinvasudevan.co.cc

According to the documentation , the width and height must be changed in #featured id. 
When I change it, the size of the image gets changed rather than the full slider itself.

http://postimage.org/image/c0wzaoq4x/

Comment: Consider posting a demo (to [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) or similar) that reproduces your problem, so we can see what's going on, and see, and edit, your code easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Works for me:***

```
/* Change CSS */

    div.orbit-wrapper {
      width: 470px !important;
      height: 255px !important;
      position: relative;
    }

/* Or Change JavaScript */

    $(window).load(function() {
      $('#featured').orbit({
        bullets: true
      });

      $('.orbit-wrapper').css({ width: 470, height: 225 });
    });
```

Comment: Tried it , Doesn't work. The documentation says that the slider adjusts itself the size of the image. Yes, the slider size does change

But I want the slider size to be fixed so my layout will be responsive.

you can download the site zip here http://ashwinvasudevan.co.cc/stackoverflow/final.zip